# MVC4 using Action Helper in Area Partial View return empty url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use MVC4 with areas. In one area I've added a controller to handle the postback of a from.

```
class MyController : Controller{ 
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Save(MyModel model){....}
}
```

This form is implemented as _form.cshtml in the areas view/shared folder.

```
<form id="Input@Html.Raw(Model.Id)" action="@Html.Action("Save", "MyController")" >
       @Html.HiddenFor( x => Model.Id)
       @Html.TextAreaFor( x => Model.Text )
       ...
</form>
```

The partial view is loaded via a helper class

```
static class MyHelper{
  public static MvcHtmlString AddInput(int id)
  {
     MyModel model = GetMyModelById(id);
     return Html.Partial("_form", model);
  } 
}
```

Now the form is added somewhere in the area be calling

```
@Html.AddInput(42);
```

The returned MvcHtmlString contains the form but the action attribute of the form is still empty.

What could this cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be using `Url.Action` instead of `Html.Action`

`Html.Action` will attempt to invoke the action method whereas you just require the link.

Comment: this would return me a <a ... tag but not the link destination itself